# Java Code to Haskell (Problems with 2D and 3D arrays)

Tags: haskell, code-translation

I have been asked to translate the following code which finds a maximum non-overlapping increasing sub sequence given a large amount of input. I haven't had much time to learn a lot on Haskell and I am stuck how to actually do it.

Here is the code in Java:

```
import java.util.*;
public class mnois {
    public static int[][] memo;
    public static int[][] lis;
    public static int[] nums;
    public static int[][][] lmemo;
    public static int n;
    public static String input;
    public static String[] arrIn;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner br = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = br.nextInt();
        for(int c = 1;c<=t;c++) {
            n = br.nextInt();
            input = br.nextLine();
            arrIn = input.split(" ");
            nums = new int[n];
            for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
                nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrIn[i]);
            }
            memo = new int[n][n+1];
            for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
                Arrays.fill(memo[i], -1);
            }
            lmemo = new int[n][n+1][n+1];
            for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j = 0;j<n+1;j++){
                    Arrays.fill(lmemo[i][j], -1);
                }
            }
            lis = new int[n][n];
            for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j = i;j<n;j++){
                    lis[i][j] = lis(i, n, j);
                }
            }
            for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++){
                System.out.print(go(0, i));
                if (i != n){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int lis(int pos, int last, int max) {
        if (pos > max) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (lmemo[pos][last][max] != -1){
            return lmemo[pos][last][max];
        }

        int best = lis(pos+1, last, max);
        if (last == n || nums[pos] > nums[last]) {
            best = Math.max(best, lis(pos+1, pos, max)+1);
        }
        return lmemo[pos][last][max] = best;
    }

    public static int go(int pos , int k){
        if (pos >= n) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (memo[pos][k] != -1){
            return memo[pos][k];
        }

        int best = go(pos+1, k);
        for(int i = pos;i<n;i++){
            if (lis[pos][i] >= k) {
                best = Math.max(best, go(i+1, k)+lis[pos][i]);
            }
        }

        return memo[pos][k] = best;
    }
}
```

I am particularly having problems with creating mutable 2D and 3D arrays. Appreciate any help I can get.

This is what I have so far:

```
import Data.Array.IO

case :: Int -> Int -> Bool
case index n = 
  if (index >= n)
    return True
  else do
    numElems :: Int <- readLn
    strElems <- readLn
    nums <- newArray_ (0, numElems) :: Int
    addElems nums 0 0 numElems strElems
    memo <- newArray ((0, 0), (strElems, strElems+1)) -1 :: IO (IOArray (Int, Int) Int)
    lmemo <- newArray (((0,0),(0,0)), ()) -1 :: IO (IOArray (Int, Int) IO (IOArray (Int, Int) Int))
    lis <- newArray ((0, 0), (strElems, strElems)) -1 :: IO (IOArray (Int, Int) Int)


addElems :: (IOArray s Int Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int -> String -> IO s ()
addElems arr startArr strIndex finish string =
  if (start >= finish) then
    return ()
  else do
    num <- digitToInt $ string !! strIndex
    writeArray arr startArr char
    addElems arr (startArr+1) (strIndex+2) finish string

lisLoop :: (IOArray s Int Int) -> Int -> Int -> IO s ()
listLoop arr start finish = 
  if (start >= finish) then
    return ()
  else do
    next 0 finish
  where
    next i currIdx len =
      if (i < len)
        writeArray arr (currIdx, i)
        next (i+1) currIdx len
```

Comment: Can you narrow this down a bit? Ideally you could identify one or two lines of the Java code that are currently blocking your translation efforts and where a bit of expertise would unblock you. If you can't narrow it down to one thing that's blocking you, probably a more broad-spectrum tutorial would be a better resource than SO.

Comment: ...and I know you say something specific ("I am particularly having problems with creating mutable 2D and 3D arrays."), but it doesn't appear to be true -- I can see that you have Haskell code that performs that task (though there are some errors that should be easily fixed by following the compiler's advice). So it's really unclear what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Are you sure you want to translate the Java to Haskell? If you could explain what the code actually does, it would be easier for us to help/suggest a solution. In particular, arrays are not really a functional data structure.